# Dart Map syntax: putIfAbsent('FirstKey',() => 1); What is: ()?

Tags: dart

In editor hint you get:

```dart
scores.putIfAbsent(key, () => numValue);
```

I am adding single "rows" to my Maps with commands:

```dart
myMap.putIfAbsent(9, () => 'Planned');
yourMap.putIfAbsent('foo', () => true);
```

so: what does that  ()   mean ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `putIfAbsent` function takes two arguments, the key and a function that will return the new value, if needed.

See https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-core.Map#id_putIfAbsent

The reason for the second argument to be a function returning the new value, and just not the value itself, is that if the map already contains the key, it's sometimes undesirable to create the value.

Consider the following example:

```
var map = ...;
var key = ...;
map.putIfAbsent(key, new Value());
```

If `map` already contains `key`, the new value object is not used at all. If the Value object is some heavy or expensive to allocate object, this is an unwanted side-effect.

By taking a function instead

```
var map = ...;
var key = ...;
map.putIfAbsent(key, () => new Value());
```

It will only execute the function if the `key` is not present in `map`, and the value is needed.

So, to answer the syntax question. A expression of the form `() => ...` is a short hand of a function expression, returning the result of the first expression. A small example:

```
var function = () => "some string";
var str = function();
print(str);
```

will print "some string".

Answer (score 0):

`()` can't be seen alone here its `() =>` that makes the difference.

```dart
// adds the value of numValue
scores.putIfAbsent(key, numValue);

// adds an (anonymous) function that takes 0 arguments and returns the value of numValue.
scores.putIfAbsent(key, () => numValue);
```

So this two forms are totally different. The first adds a value and the second adds a function.

When we assume `numValue` has the value `5` when `putIfAbsent` is called then in the first case

```dart
var x = scores[key];
// here var x has the value 5
```

and in the second case

```dart
var x = scores[key];
// here var x references a function
var y = x();
// calling the function executes its body which is `return numValue` (the `return` is implicit in the shorthand function form)
// here var y has the value 5
```

Comment: To be clear, `putIfAbsent`'s second argument isn't the value but a function that returns the value; so you can't add a `new Value()` (unless `Value` `implements` `Function`) and to add a function as a value you would have to say `putIfAbsent(key, () => () => value)`.

Comment: I realized this already after I saw Anders' answer but I still think my answer helps to understand the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`()` indicates that the expression doesn't have any input parameters.